# rails metasearch undefined method 'company_id'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, meta-search

I'm new to rails and need your help for what should be a simple problem.

when I run this code:

```
@search = User.search(params[:search])
@foundusers = @search.all.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 20
@user = @search.where("users.id = ?", params[:id])
if @user.nil?
  @user = @foundusers.first
end
unless @user.company_id.nil?
  @company = Company.find(@user.company_id)
end
```

I get following error statement: 
undefined method `company_id' for #

I dont understand because the query on the database is correct (SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` LEFT OUTER JOIN `companies` ON `companies`.`id` = `users`.`company_id` WHERE (((`users`.`firstname` LIKE '%s%' OR `users`.`lastname` LIKE '%s%') OR `companies`.`name` LIKE '%s%')) AND (users.id = '11'))

and the company_id for this user is not empty.

When I type puts @user.name, instead of giving me the user name, it gives me 'User'

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user.name prints User because .where("users.id = ?", params[:id]) still return an array

Try this

```
@users = @search.where("users.id = ?", params[:id])
@user = @users.nil? ? @foundusers.first : @users.first
```